# how to get a database datetime value as a date only?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

hello I want to save a date with datetime datatype in sql server. In the search screen i am giving parameter as only date.

So how can i set as query? my code is:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource 
     ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TAXIConnectionString %>" 
     SelectCommand="SELECT [TripId] FROM [BookingMaster] 
              WHERE ( ([PickupDateTime] = @PickupDateTime or @PickupDateTime is null))" 
     CancelSelectOnNullParameter="False">
     <SelectParameters>
         <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtBookingDate" 
              Name="PickupDateTime" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" 
              ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" />
     </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: +1 for `help me in advance`

Comment: What DB provider are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your using Sql2008 or later you can use the DATE type. Your select command would look like.

```
SelectCommand="SELECT [TripId] FROM [BookingMaster] 
              WHERE ( (cast([PickupDateTime] as date) = @PickupDateTime or @PickupDateTime is null))"
```

Comment: the `CONVERT` function has the same execution plan if you're more familiar with it: `WHERE ( (convert(date, PickupDateTime) = @PickupDateTime or @PickupDateTime is null))`